# Failed to integrate Hibernate object with Javax DI

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to set up demo maven project from scratch but I am having hard time injecting hibernate object into REST controller. So far I have following dependencies

- Maven
- Spring Boot
- Jersey 2.7

I have also added hibernate and postgresql driver dependencies and also I am using java configuration for data source initialization. I am able to start the server but as soon as I visit end point application fails with following exception:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=ProductDao,parent=ProductsResource,qualifiers={}),position=0,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,106121749)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:232)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:249)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:414)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:160)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2445)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:621)
at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:173)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:128)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:131)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:110)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:65)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

REST Controller:

```
package com.discount.resources;

import com.discount.persistance.ProductDao;
import com.discount.representations.Product;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;


@Path("/products")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProductsResource {
    private ProductDao productDao;
    @Inject
    public ProductsResource(ProductDao productDao){
        this.productDao = productDao;
    }

@GET
public List<Product> getAll(){
    return this.productDao.findAll();
}
```

}

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.discount</groupId>
<artifactId>discount-rest-services</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Spring -->
    <!-- Postgres -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- End Postgres -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JDBI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbi</artifactId>
        <version>2.53</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Jersey -->

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Jackson -->
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.discount.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Java SQL initialization:

```
package com.discount.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.discount.persistence")
public class SqlInitialization implements RepositoryConfig {

@Bean
@Override
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/discount-listing");
    dataSource.setUsername("neowinian");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
@Override
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.discount.representations");
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(new Properties() {{
        put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", SpringSessionContext.class.getName());
    }});
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {{
        setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
    }});
    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

}

Edit:

Application:

```
package com.discount;

import com.discount.config.JerseyInitialization;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).run(args);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/*");
    registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyInitialization.class.getName());
    return registration;
}
}
```

ProductDao

```
package com.discount.persistance;

import com.discount.representations.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ProductDao extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

Comment: And there should be because? Add your `Application` class. Regarding your config `spring-tx` is already included by using the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` depenency, next to that the current version conflicts with the other Spring jars in your project!.

Comment: Support for Jersey 2 is new in Spring Boot 1.2. There isn't much to it, so you could copy the code over to your project. Or you could upgrade to 1.2.0.RC1 (the latest release candidate).

Comment: @M.Deinum I've edited my post by adding Application and ProductDao. Also, I've removed spring-tx dependency but I'm still getting same error.

Comment: Make sure that you have setup the Jersey Spring Integration correctly, without it it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it. It was cause because of missing dependency **jersey-spring3**

Now my pom.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.discount</groupId>
<artifactId>discount-rest-services</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Spring -->

    <!-- Postgres -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Postgres -->

    <!-- Jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Jersey -->

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- End Jackson -->
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.discount.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```